# Custom weighted binary cross entropy according to output values

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, conv-neural-network

In tensorflow I have the input in shape (...,100) like **[0.21630094, 0.21316614, 0.21630094 ...]**
values between (0 to 1), and I have the output with also 100 size that only contains 0 and 1 values like **[0 1 0 1 0 0 ...]**. I have created CNN using keras/tensorflow with the following output layer:

```
model.add(layers.Dense(100, activation='sigmoid'))
```

I am using binary cross entropy as an loss function like:

```
model.compile(optimizer=opt,
          loss='binary_crossentropy',
          metrics=['acc'])
```

In my data I can say that the probabilty of 1 values occur in output is %5-10. In order words only 5-10 values are 1, all of the other values are 0 in output. So when I trained my model accurancy rapidly becomes %90, after that do no increase. The following prediction result shows that my model tends to predict 0 values only.

```
[0.00990906 0.00991494 0.0100315  0.00985315 0.00996962 0.01004039 0.00997209 ..]
```

My question that how can I increase the effect of 1 values in output on loss function. I could not use class weights since I can not know 1 values occurs in which node of output layer.

Comment: You can use something like a custom weighted loss function. you can look at weighted dice loss (somthing similar) which gives more importance to the 1's than 0's.

Comment: Which optimizer are you using ? If you are using ```sdg``` as an optimizer, which usually performs poorly on CNN. Please use ```adam```.

Comment: Be sure the two classes are set right (i.e imbalanced data). If you have loaded your samples in a way that your classes are wrong, your model is going to learn nothing.

Answer (score 1):

It seems data having `class imbalance` problem, hence you are getting 5 to 10 % of outputs as `1`.

Common techniques for dealing with imbalanced data like:

1. Class weighting
2. Oversampling

Code:

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras
import os
import tempfile

import matplotlib as mpl
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns

import sklearn
from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler

mpl.rcParams['figure.figsize'] = (12, 10)
colors = plt.rcParams['axes.prop_cycle'].by_key()['color']

# Download the Kaggle Credit Card Fraud data set
file = tf.keras.utils
raw_df = pd.read_csv('https://storage.googleapis.com/download.tensorflow.org/data/creditcard.csv')
raw_df.head()

raw_df[['Time', 'V1', 'V2', 'V3', 'V4', 'V5', 'V26', 'V27', 'V28', 'Amount', 'Class']].describe()

# Examine the class label imbalance
neg, pos = np.bincount(raw_df['Class'])
total = neg + pos
print('Examples:\n    Total: {}\n    Positive: {} ({:.2f}% of total)\n'.format(
    total, pos, 100 * pos / total))

# Clean, split and normalize the data
cleaned_df = raw_df.copy()

# You don't want the `Time` column.
cleaned_df.pop('Time')

# The `Amount` column covers a huge range. Convert to log-space.
eps=0.001 # 0 => 0.1¢
cleaned_df['Log Amount'] = np.log(cleaned_df.pop('Amount')+eps)

# Use a utility from sklearn to split and shuffle our dataset.
train_df, test_df = train_test_split(cleaned_df, test_size=0.2)
train_df, val_df = train_test_split(train_df, test_size=0.2)

# Form np arrays of labels and features.
train_labels = np.array(train_df.pop('Class'))
bool_train_labels = train_labels != 0
val_labels = np.array(val_df.pop('Class'))
test_labels = np.array(test_df.pop('Class'))

train_features = np.array(train_df)
val_features = np.array(val_df)
test_features = np.array(test_df)

scaler = StandardScaler()
train_features = scaler.fit_transform(train_features)

val_features = scaler.transform(val_features)
test_features = scaler.transform(test_features)

train_features = np.clip(train_features, -5, 5)
val_features = np.clip(val_features, -5, 5)
test_features = np.clip(test_features, -5, 5)


print('Training labels shape:', train_labels.shape)
print('Validation labels shape:', val_labels.shape)
print('Test labels shape:', test_labels.shape)

print('Training features shape:', train_features.shape)
print('Validation features shape:', val_features.shape)
print('Test features shape:', test_features.shape)

#Look at the data distribution

pos_df = pd.DataFrame(train_features[ bool_train_labels], columns = train_df.columns)
neg_df = pd.DataFrame(train_features[~bool_train_labels], columns = train_df.columns)

sns.jointplot(pos_df['V5'], pos_df['V6'],
              kind='hex', xlim = (-5,5), ylim = (-5,5))
plt.suptitle("Positive distribution")

sns.jointplot(neg_df['V5'], neg_df['V6'],
              kind='hex', xlim = (-5,5), ylim = (-5,5))
_ = plt.suptitle("Negative distribution")

# Define the model and metrics
METRICS = [
      keras.metrics.TruePositives(name='tp'),
      keras.metrics.FalsePositives(name='fp'),
      keras.metrics.TrueNegatives(name='tn'),
      keras.metrics.FalseNegatives(name='fn'), 
      keras.metrics.BinaryAccuracy(name='accuracy'),
      keras.metrics.Precision(name='precision'),
      keras.metrics.Recall(name='recall'),
      keras.metrics.AUC(name='auc'),
]

def make_model(metrics = METRICS, output_bias=None):
  if output_bias is not None:
    output_bias = tf.keras.initializers.Constant(output_bias)
  model = keras.Sequential([
      keras.layers.Dense(
          16, activation='relu',
          input_shape=(train_features.shape[-1],)),
      keras.layers.Dropout(0.5),
      keras.layers.Dense(1, activation='sigmoid',
                         bias_initializer=output_bias),
  ])

  model.compile(
      optimizer=keras.optimizers.Adam(lr=1e-3),
      loss=keras.losses.BinaryCrossentropy(),
      metrics=metrics)

  return model

# Baseline model
# Build the model

EPOCHS = 100
BATCH_SIZE = 2048

early_stopping = tf.keras.callbacks.EarlyStopping(
    monitor='val_auc', 
    verbose=1,
    patience=10,
    mode='max',
    restore_best_weights=True)

model = make_model()
model.summary()

# Test run the model:
model.predict(train_features[:10])

results = model.evaluate(train_features, train_labels, batch_size=BATCH_SIZE, verbose=0)
print("Loss: {:0.4f}".format(results[0]))

#Optional: Set the correct initial bias

initial_bias = np.log([pos/neg])
initial_bias

model = make_model(output_bias = initial_bias)
model.predict(train_features[:10])

results = model.evaluate(train_features, train_labels, batch_size=BATCH_SIZE, verbose=0)
print("Loss: {:0.4f}".format(results[0]))

# Checkpoint the initial weights

initial_weights = os.path.join(tempfile.mkdtemp(),'initial_weights')
model.save_weights(initial_weights)

# Confirm that the bias fix helps

model = make_model()
model.load_weights(initial_weights)
model.layers[-1].bias.assign([0.0])
zero_bias_history = model.fit(
    train_features,
    train_labels,
    batch_size=BATCH_SIZE,
    epochs=20,
    validation_data=(val_features, val_labels), 
    verbose=0)

model = make_model()
model.load_weights(initial_weights)
careful_bias_history = model.fit(
    train_features,
    train_labels,
    batch_size=BATCH_SIZE,
    epochs=20,
    validation_data=(val_features, val_labels), 
    verbose=0)

def plot_loss(history, label, n):
  # Use a log scale to show the wide range of values.
  plt.semilogy(history.epoch,  history.history['loss'],
               color=colors[n], label='Train '+label)
  plt.semilogy(history.epoch,  history.history['val_loss'],
          color=colors[n], label='Val '+label,
          linestyle="--")
  plt.xlabel('Epoch')
  plt.ylabel('Loss')

  plt.legend()

plot_loss(zero_bias_history, "Zero Bias", 0)
plot_loss(careful_bias_history, "Careful Bias", 1)

# Train the model

model = make_model()
model.load_weights(initial_weights)
baseline_history = model.fit(
    train_features,
    train_labels,
    batch_size=BATCH_SIZE,
    epochs=EPOCHS,
    callbacks = [early_stopping],
    validation_data=(val_features, val_labels))

# Check training history

def plot_metrics(history):
  metrics =  ['loss', 'auc', 'precision', 'recall']
  for n, metric in enumerate(metrics):
    name = metric.replace("_"," ").capitalize()
    plt.subplot(2,2,n+1)
    plt.plot(history.epoch,  history.history[metric], color=colors[0], label='Train')
    plt.plot(history.epoch, history.history['val_'+metric],
             color=colors[0], linestyle="--", label='Val')
    plt.xlabel('Epoch')
    plt.ylabel(name)
    if metric == 'loss':
      plt.ylim([0, plt.ylim()[1]])
    elif metric == 'auc':
      plt.ylim([0.8,1])
    else:
      plt.ylim([0,1])

    plt.legend()

plot_metrics(baseline_history)

# Evaluate metrics

train_predictions_baseline = model.predict(train_features, batch_size=BATCH_SIZE)
test_predictions_baseline = model.predict(test_features, batch_size=BATCH_SIZE)

def plot_cm(labels, predictions, p=0.5):
  cm = confusion_matrix(labels, predictions > p)
  plt.figure(figsize=(5,5))
  sns.heatmap(cm, annot=True, fmt="d")
  plt.title('Confusion matrix @{:.2f}'.format(p))
  plt.ylabel('Actual label')
  plt.xlabel('Predicted label')

  print('Legitimate Transactions Detected (True Negatives): ', cm[0][0])
  print('Legitimate Transactions Incorrectly Detected (False Positives): ', cm[0][1])
  print('Fraudulent Transactions Missed (False Negatives): ', cm[1][0])
  print('Fraudulent Transactions Detected (True Positives): ', cm[1][1])
  print('Total Fraudulent Transactions: ', np.sum(cm[1]))

baseline_results = model.evaluate(test_features, test_labels,
                                  batch_size=BATCH_SIZE, verbose=0)
for name, value in zip(model.metrics_names, baseline_results):
  print(name, ': ', value)
print()

plot_cm(test_labels, test_predictions_baseline)

#Plot the ROC

def plot_roc(name, labels, predictions, **kwargs):
  fp, tp, _ = sklearn.metrics.roc_curve(labels, predictions)

  plt.plot(100*fp, 100*tp, label=name, linewidth=2, **kwargs)
  plt.xlabel('False positives [%]')
  plt.ylabel('True positives [%]')
  plt.xlim([-0.5,20])
  plt.ylim([80,100.5])
  plt.grid(True)
  ax = plt.gca()
  ax.set_aspect('equal')

plot_roc("Train Baseline", train_labels, train_predictions_baseline, color=colors[0])
plot_roc("Test Baseline", test_labels, test_predictions_baseline, color=colors[0], linestyle='--')
plt.legend(loc='lower right')

#
### Class weights ###
#Calculate class weights

# Scaling by total/2 helps keep the loss to a similar magnitude.
# The sum of the weights of all examples stays the same.
weight_for_0 = (1 / neg)*(total)/2.0 
weight_for_1 = (1 / pos)*(total)/2.0

class_weight = {0: weight_for_0, 1: weight_for_1}

print('Weight for class 0: {:.2f}'.format(weight_for_0))
print('Weight for class 1: {:.2f}'.format(weight_for_1))

# Train a model with class weights

weighted_model = make_model()
weighted_model.load_weights(initial_weights)

weighted_history = weighted_model.fit(
    train_features,
    train_labels,
    batch_size=BATCH_SIZE,
    epochs=EPOCHS,
    callbacks = [early_stopping],
    validation_data=(val_features, val_labels),
    # The class weights go here
    class_weight=class_weight) 

#Check training history

plot_metrics(weighted_history)

# Evaluate metrics

train_predictions_weighted = weighted_model.predict(train_features, batch_size=BATCH_SIZE)
test_predictions_weighted = weighted_model.predict(test_features, batch_size=BATCH_SIZE)

weighted_results = weighted_model.evaluate(test_features, test_labels,
                                           batch_size=BATCH_SIZE, verbose=0)
for name, value in zip(weighted_model.metrics_names, weighted_results):
  print(name, ': ', value)
print()

plot_cm(test_labels, test_predictions_weighted)

# Plot the ROC

plot_roc("Train Baseline", train_labels, train_predictions_baseline, color=colors[0])
plot_roc("Test Baseline", test_labels, test_predictions_baseline, color=colors[0], linestyle='--')

plot_roc("Train Weighted", train_labels, train_predictions_weighted, color=colors[1])
plot_roc("Test Weighted", test_labels, test_predictions_weighted, color=colors[1], linestyle='--')


plt.legend(loc='lower right')


### Oversampling ###

pos_features = train_features[bool_train_labels]
neg_features = train_features[~bool_train_labels]

pos_labels = train_labels[bool_train_labels]
neg_labels = train_labels[~bool_train_labels]

# You can balance the dataset manually by choosing the right number of random indices from the positive examples:

ids = np.arange(len(pos_features))
choices = np.random.choice(ids, len(neg_features))

res_pos_features = pos_features[choices]
res_pos_labels = pos_labels[choices]

res_pos_features.shape

resampled_features = np.concatenate([res_pos_features, neg_features], axis=0)
resampled_labels = np.concatenate([res_pos_labels, neg_labels], axis=0)

order = np.arange(len(resampled_labels))
np.random.shuffle(order)
resampled_features = resampled_features[order]
resampled_labels = resampled_labels[order]

resampled_features.shape

# Using tf.data

BUFFER_SIZE = 100000

def make_ds(features, labels):
  ds = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((features, labels))#.cache()
  ds = ds.shuffle(BUFFER_SIZE).repeat()
  return ds

pos_ds = make_ds(pos_features, pos_labels)
neg_ds = make_ds(neg_features, neg_labels)


for features, label in pos_ds.take(1):
  print("Features:\n", features.numpy())
  print()
  print("Label: ", label.numpy())

resampled_ds = tf.data.experimental.sample_from_datasets([pos_ds, neg_ds], weights=[0.5, 0.5])
resampled_ds = resampled_ds.batch(BATCH_SIZE).prefetch(2)

for features, label in resampled_ds.take(1):
  print(label.numpy().mean())

# Train on the oversampled data

resampled_model = make_model()
resampled_model.load_weights(initial_weights)

# Reset the bias to zero, since this dataset is balanced.
output_layer = resampled_model.layers[-1] 
output_layer.bias.assign([0])

val_ds = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((val_features, val_labels)).cache()
val_ds = val_ds.batch(BATCH_SIZE).prefetch(2) 

resampled_history = resampled_model.fit(
    resampled_ds,
    epochs=EPOCHS,
    steps_per_epoch=resampled_steps_per_epoch,
    callbacks = [early_stopping],
    validation_data=val_ds)

# Check training history

plot_metrics(resampled_history )

# Re-train

resampled_model = make_model()
resampled_model.load_weights(initial_weights)

# Reset the bias to zero, since this dataset is balanced.
output_layer = resampled_model.layers[-1] 
output_layer.bias.assign([0])

resampled_history = resampled_model.fit(
    resampled_ds,
    # These are not real epochs
    steps_per_epoch = 20,
    epochs=10*EPOCHS,
    callbacks = [early_stopping],
    validation_data=(val_ds))

# Re-check training history 
plot_metrics(resampled_history)


# Evaluate metrics

train_predictions_resampled = resampled_model.predict(train_features, batch_size=BATCH_SIZE)
test_predictions_resampled = resampled_model.predict(test_features, batch_size=BATCH_SIZE)

resampled_results = resampled_model.evaluate(test_features, test_labels,
                                             batch_size=BATCH_SIZE, verbose=0)
for name, value in zip(resampled_model.metrics_names, resampled_results):
  print(name, ': ', value)
print()

plot_cm(test_labels, test_predictions_resampled)

# Plot the ROC

plot_roc("Train Baseline", train_labels, train_predictions_baseline, color=colors[0])
plot_roc("Test Baseline", test_labels, test_predictions_baseline, color=colors[0], linestyle='--')

plot_roc("Train Weighted", train_labels, train_predictions_weighted, color=colors[1])
plot_roc("Test Weighted", test_labels, test_predictions_weighted, color=colors[1], linestyle='--')

plot_roc("Train Resampled", train_labels, train_predictions_resampled,  color=colors[2])
plot_roc("Test Resampled", test_labels, test_predictions_resampled,  color=colors[2], linestyle='--')
plt.legend(loc='lower right')
```

Please follow this [link](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/structured_data/imbalanced_data) for more information.